# What kind of vulnerability would this exploit?

Tags: exploit, cookies

We're currently having our website pentested, and looking through our logs, a cookie we set (our `allowCookies` cookie) has had the value set to `http%3a%2f%2fawebsite.net%2ff517a2bc19bdff66d7c64e8a7ad2f043.txt`. That text file contains the string `3ac3bbfe0cb16c0ff90fc0c0fcb21764`.

What kind of vulnerability would this exploit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intent would have been to exploit a server side include -- your webserver retrieving the URL and incorporating it into the web page.

This vulnerability isn't very common anymore.

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought it was maybe trying to get the file included in the webpage. Would that be an include coded by myself, or is it something older webservers used to do?

Comment: It would be something coded by yourself. The pentesting tool they're using likely attempts this with every cookie it sees being set.

Comment: I've noticed the url did move between cookies. That will also explain why the url ../../../../../etc/passwd was tested a few times then!